# Codeigniter search query combining keywords

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, search

I want a search query to return results that match **all keywords**, but I can only get it to either **match any** or **match string**.

I.E. "cake chocolate" either returns all records with "cake" OR "chocolate" in a tag field, or results with the exact tag "cake chocolate", as opposed to what I want, which is to get any record with "cake" AND "chocolate". Here is what I've got:

```
$key = $this->input->post('searchTerm');
         if($key != ''){
        // if I comment out the next 10 lines, it becomes MATCH-ANY
           $this->db->or_like('product_name',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('product_code',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('description',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('season',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('year',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('photo_style',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('photo_status',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('extra_field1',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('extra_field2',$key);
           $this->db->or_like('additional_notes',$key); 
        // But if I comment out the next 7 lines instead, I match only the entire string.
        $Singlequry = "select  * from (select *,    concat_ws(' ',product_name,product_code,description,season,year,photo_style,photo_status,extra_field1,extra_field2,additional_notes) merged from records )temp where "; 
        $keywordsMany = explode(' ',$key);
        $tempQuery = array();
        foreach($keywordsMany as $each){
        $tempQuery[] = " temp.merged like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($each)."%'";
        }
        $Singlequry = $Singlequry.implode(' or ',$tempQuery);        // end of search type comment-out   
           $makeQuery = true;
         }
```

In case it's not obvious, I really have no idea what I'm doing. I've thrown `where_in` and other stuff in place of the `or_like` but with no luck. All this to say, I will need a little hand-holding:)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot produce this query with codeigniter or_like;
Your current code produce your query like this

```
SELECT * from tablename WhHERE product_name like '%key%' or product_code like '%key%' OR..............
```

which will return only any match with the key.

BUT I guess you want all match which should be like this

```
SELECT * from tablename WhHERE product_name like '%key%' AND product_code like '%key%' AND..............
```

if so you can replace your `or_like` with `where` like followings

```
 $this->db->where("product_name LIKE '%$key%'");
 $this->db->where("product_code LIKE '%$key%'");
 $this->db->where("description LIKE '%$key%'");
```

It will produce your expected query.It will return results which has all match with key.
You can do it many other way too.
Hope it will will help you.